# recursive induction regarding two recursive functions

Tags: induction

Consider the following recursive definitions of two functions from $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$

$$ F(n) =
\begin{cases} 
      1 & n = 0 \\
      2 & n = 1 \\
      F(n-2)^2 \cdot F(n-1) & n > 1
   \end{cases}
$$

$$ G(n) =
\begin{cases} 
      1 & n = 0 \\
      2G(n-1)^2 & n > 0 \text{ and n is odd } \\
      G(n-1)^2/2 & n > 0 \text{ and n is even }
   \end{cases}
$$

Use induction to prove $F(n) = G(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

ANSWER: \

Basis:

For $n = 0$,

$F(0) = 1 = G(0)$ [By definition of G and F].

Therefore $F(n) = G(n)$ as wanted

For $n = 1$,

$F(1) = 2$ [By definition of F]

$= 2(1)^2$ [manipulated numbers]

$= 2G(0)^2$ [By definition of G(0)]

$= 2G(1-1)^2$ [manipulated numbers]

$= G(1)$ [definition of G when n is odd]

Therefore $F(n) = G(n)$ as wanted

Ind step: Let $n \geq 2$. Suppose $F(j) = G(j)$ whenever $0 \leq j < n$ [I.H]

WTP: $F(n) = G(n)$

Two cases: When n is even and odd

let n be an odd number:

$F(n) = F(n-2)^2 \cdot F(n-1)$ [Definition of F; $n > 1$]

$= G(n-2)^2 \cdot G(n-1)$ [I.H]

$= 2G(n-1) \cdot G(n-1)$ [Definition of G; $n > 0$ and even]

$= 2G(n-1)^2$

$= G(n)$ [Definition of G; $n > 0$ and odd], holds

let n be an even number

$F(n) = F(n-2)^2 \cdot F(n-1)$ [Definition of F; $n > 1$]

$= G(n-2)^2 \cdot G(n-1)$ [I.H]

$= \frac{G(n-1)}{2} \cdot G(n-1)$ [Definition of G; $n > 0$ and odd]

$= G(n-1)^2/2$

$= G(n)$ [Definition of G; $n > 0$ and even], holds

therefore $F(n) = G(n)$ as wanted

Would this proof be correct?